# linear regression for timeseries python (numpy or pandas)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels

I am new to python and programming in general, so forgive any simple mistakes/ things that should be obvious.

What I am trying to do is quite simple, I just want to fit a linear trend (1-d polynomial) to a bunch of time-series to see whether the slopes are positive or negative. Right now I am just trying to get it to work for one time series.

The problem: it seems like both pandas and numpy can't do regressions for datetimes. My date times are not regular (generally 1 day per month but not the same day) so can't use the suggestion posed in [Linear Regression from Time Series Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425490/linear-regression-from-time-series-pandas/30431930#30431930)

My time series csv looks like:

```
StationName,    year,   month,  day,    depth,  NO3-N,  PO4-P,  TotP,   TotN,
Kvarnbacken (Savaran),  2003,   2,  25, 0.5,    46, 9,  14, 451
Kvarnbacken (Savaran),  2003,   3,  18, 0.5,    64, 15, 17, 310
Kvarnbacken (Savaran),  2003,   3,  31, 0.5,    76, 7,  19, 566
```

so far what i have is

```
import datetime as dt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

# read in station csv file
data = pd.read_csv('Kvarnbacken (Savaran)_2003.csv')
data.head()
# set up dates to something python can recognize
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.year*10000+data.month *
                          100+data.day, format='%Y%m%d')
```

I tried

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data.date,
                                                               data.TotP)
```

and got the error
    TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('

I also tried

```
coefP = np.polyfit(data.date, data.TotP, 1)
polyP = np.poly1d(coefP)
ys = polyP(data.date)
print 'For P: coef, poly'
print coefP
print polyP
```

and got the same error.

I am guessing the easiest way around this is to do something where I just count the days since the first measurement I have and then just do a regression with days_since to the total phosphorous concentration (totP) but I am not sure of the easiest way to do that or if there was another trick.

Comment: What you are doing seems wrong to me as the gap between two days is not constant (exple: between the 31st of Dec and the 1st of Jan). You could say day 0 is your first date. Then substract this first date to every date and convert it in days.

Comment: Hugo you are definitely correct. I didn't really think through my quick fix.

Comment: Comment #1 is not a great approach.  If you want to do something like that you ought to convert it into some common units.  More like 365*year + 30*month + days.  Although even that is not ideal because years and months don't have a constant number of days.  See answer for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

You could convert the datetime to days in the following way.

```
data['days_since'] = (data.date - pd.to_datetime('2003-02-25') ).astype('timedelta64[D]')

        date  days_since
0 2003-02-25           0
1 2003-03-18          21
2 2003-03-31          34
```

Now you should be able to regress as you did above.

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data.days_since, 
                                                               data.TotP)
slope, intercept
(0.1466591166477916, 13.977916194790488)
```

You might also want to consider other regression options such as the [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) package, especially if you'll be doing this sort of thing very often.  (Note that x and y are reversed compared to linregress)

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

smf.ols( 'TotP ~ days_since', data=data ).fit().params

Intercept     13.977916
days_since     0.146659
```

That's just a fraction of the statsmodels output btw (use `summary()` instead of `params` to get the extra output.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar but was stuck with how to get the 'day_since' as an integer, that astype is a nice trick.